# Leaflet + JQuery Mobile Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, leaflet

I have a website that uses JQuery Mobile and Leaflet. At start the map is loaded fine, but when I enter in another page and go then back to homepage with my map, it looks like this:

[image]

There is no network error or any other errors.. The tiles are downloaded fine but they are just not shown together and only one tile is shown, everything else is black.
I don't do anything special when I go to the other page. I have also tried to comment everything but it is still the same..
Has anyone else experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you switch to another page, the map's containing element style gets changed and as you can see, it doesn't like that. Catch the `pagecontainershow` event which gets fired every time a page is shown, check if it's your map's page and then call the `invalidateSize` method of your mapinstance so it updates your map. That should do the trick.

```
// Attach event handler to pagecontainershow event
// This will execute every time a page is shown/ready
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function(e, ui) {
    // Get the id of the currently active page
    var pageId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop('id');
    // Check if the id matches the id of your map's page
    if (pageId == 'id_of_your_map_page') {
        // It's a match, invalidate the map so it resets
        map.invalidateSize();
        // Assuming 'map' holds a reference to your map instance
    }
});
```

https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-invalidatesize

Comment: ah ok but I simply have a data-rel="back" button to go back to my homepage.. Do you say I should use a show event function?

Comment: I've added some code to clarify things. Hope that helps